# How do I rebuild after deleting the release folder in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-neon

I deleted the release folder which was generated by eclipse (CDT) when I first built my project; but now when I try rebuilding the sources, eclipse does not regenerate the complete release folder along with the make files. Rather, it reports the following error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project '<project name>'.
Resource '/<project name>/Release/objects.mk' does not exist.
Resource '/<project name>/Release/objects.mk' does not exist.
```

I'm using `eclipse neon2` with `cdt`. I tried searching for a solution online, but I couldn't find any. How do I solve this problem and regenerate the `release` file?

Answer (score 2):

I tried refreshing the project, by right clicking the project in the `project explorer` and then clicking `refresh` before building the project. The project now builds without any problems and the release folder got regenerated.

It would have been nice if Eclipse did that automatically.

Comment: Did you try the Clean option on the Project menu next to the Build option?

Comment: @Sreram for historical reasons this isn't the default, but I recommend under Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> check Refresh Automatically.

Comment: @Jonah Graham Thanks, it worked. Now it happens automatically.